# MacBook's Airport not working from menu bar

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, airport

All of the sudden my MacBook doesn't connect to my wireless after waking from sleep.  My network shows up at full signal strength and it remembers the password correctly, but I get an error message when I try to connect from the menu bar.  The only way I can get on the internet is to go through Network Diagnostics and turn it on there.  I don't understand why it works every time through Network Diagnostics and never on it's own or through the airport menu bar.

Nothing has been changed or installed or reset on my computer that I know of.  Restarting doesn't fix it, nor does turning off the airport card.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Mac OS X? What does the system log say? What does the kernel log say? Try enabling extra logging with

Snow Leopard:
    sudo /usr/libexec/airportd debug +AllUserland +AllDriver +AllVendor

Leopard:
    sudo /usr/libexec/airportd -d

...then reproduce the problem and see what the system log (and in Snow Leopard, also the kernel log) says.

Comment: ahh no snow leopard.  i'm running leopard.  i just did a software update (which i avoid for this reason) and it didn't fix anything

Comment: I almost forgot you can enable *some* additional debug on Leopard with "sudo /usr/libexec/airportd -d". And you still have a system log.